# How to detect and convert monthly data to NaN if there is n consecutive NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
         CODE      DATE     TMAX
0        000130 1963-09-01   NaN
1        000130 1963-09-02  29.4
2        000130 1963-09-03  27.8
3        000130 1963-09-04  25.0
4        000130 1963-09-05  27.8
        ...        ...   ...
7393858  158328 2020-12-27  12.2
7393859  158328 2020-12-28   8.8
7393860  158328 2020-12-29   NaN
7393861  158328 2020-12-30  10.3
7393862  158328 2020-12-31   9.2

[7393863 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to convert the values of `df['TMAX']` to NaN if there is 5 or more consecutive NaN in 1 month. This must be done by month and by code.

For example:

```
         CODE      DATE     TMAX   
0        000130 1963-09-01   NaN
1        000130 1963-09-02   NaN
2        000130 1963-09-03   NaN
3        000130 1963-09-04   NaN
4        000130 1963-09-05   NaN
5        000130 1963-09-06  27.8
6        000130 1963-09-07  27.8
7        000130 1963-09-08  27.8
8        000130 1963-09-09  27.8
        ...        ...   ...
```

Expected df:

```
         CODE      DATE     TMAX   
0        000130 1963-09-01   NaN
1        000130 1963-09-02   NaN
2        000130 1963-09-03   NaN
3        000130 1963-09-04   NaN
4        000130 1963-09-05   NaN
5        000130 1963-09-06   NaN
6        000130 1963-09-07   NaN
7        000130 1963-09-08   NaN
8        000130 1963-09-09   NaN
        ...        ...   ...
```

So i got this code:

```
def consecutivenan(d, n=5):
    if d.isnull().astype(int).groupby(d.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).sum().ge(n).any():
        return np.nan 
    else:
        return d


df["TMAX"] = df.groupby(["CODE", df.DATE.dt.year, df.DATE.dt.month], as_index=False)["TMAX"].transform(consecutivenan, n=5)
```

And it's working perfectly but it takes 15 minutes to process the code.

Do you have any suggestion/code to make this code more efficient and fastest?

PD: I have a laptop of 24 GB ram and 2.7Ghz with 4 nucleus. In the file i have 7 millions of rows, thats why maybe this take too long.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right logic but the code could be simplified. You don't need to compute twice the `isnull`/`notnull`, nor to convert booleans to integers.

I am also testing a `cumcount` rather than `sum` here.

Can you try this potential improvement?

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

def consecutivenan(d, n=5):
    s = d.notnull()
    if s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount().eq(n-1).any():
        return np.nan 
    else:
        return d

df["TMAX"] = df.groupby(["CODE", df['DATE'].dt.to_period('M')], as_index=False)["TMAX"].transform(consecutivenan, n=5)
```

Output:

```
   CODE       DATE  TMAX
0   130 1963-09-01   NaN
1   130 1963-09-02   NaN
2   130 1963-09-03   NaN
3   130 1963-09-04   NaN
4   130 1963-09-05   NaN
5   130 1963-09-06   NaN
6   130 1963-09-07   NaN
7   130 1963-09-08   NaN
8   130 1963-09-09   NaN
```

Comment: thanks, i tried your improvement but is not working propertly.  It's turning monthly df['TMAX'] data to NaN when there are only 4 NaN. I tried with n=6 and i got the same error.

Comment: @Javier strange, I tested again on the provided sample and I get replacement for n = 4 or 5, but not 6, as expected

Comment: when i get 4 NaNs in the beginning (1,2,3 and 4 of March 1991) and in the final days of the month (28,29,30,31 of March 1991) it turns all to NaN. But there aren't at least 5 consecutive NaNs just 4, in both sides.